# Which method to use when an image does not exist

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, curl

I am currently using the php `file_exist` method to check if an image exist and to display the default image if it doesn't:

```
if(file_exists($image_location))
{
 echo "<img src='$image_location'>";
}
else
{
 echo "<img src='default_image.jpg'>";
}
```

Other than doing the above, I know that can:

1) Style the `<img>` tag with a background image

2) Use javascript `onerror` method to replace the missing image

If the image is hosted remotely,

3) Generate a HEAD request using cURL to detect the presence of the image or

4) Use the jquery `ajaxComplete` event

I think each method has its advantages and disadvantages. My long-term intention is to host the image separately, so all four options should be feasible. But which would be the better one and why?

Comment: I'd go with method 2 using javascript because it's completely handled on the client side and frees processing resources from the server.  I wouldn't use ajax, because if you're going to use javascript and run the risk of a delay in displaying the image, you might as well use the simple approach.  Using the tag with a background image guarantees that both images are loaded each time, even if only one will be displayed.  In situations where the background image loads first due to latency issues, it could end up "flickering".

Comment: @GigaWatt: good point there about loading of both image and background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `file_exists()` check for each image on each page requests sounds extremely over-the-top; is your environment that unstable!?

#1 and #2 sound like your best bet. Out of those 2, I'd choose #2 as a background image has different behaviour to the `src` attribute (e.g. how the image is resized/ repeated if it doesn't fit within the image bounds).

Be sure do avoid doing #3 for each image for each request; you'll slow down your page load infinitely (making a HTTP connection for *each* image on the page). If you want to do this, consider having a task which runs on a cron which does this for you.

Ultimately, you *shouldn't* be in an environment where images are becoming unavailable so often.

Comment: Points taken. Let me get a few more answers.

Answer (score 1):

5) setup your web-server to show default image, involving no PHP at all.
Something like

```
<directory /images>
ErrorDocument 404 /images/default.jpg
</directory>
```

Comment: Hi Colonel Shrapnel, I can understand the answers given by others, but your one requires further elaboration. Does it work if I have to show different default images based on different scenarios?

Answer (score 0):

we use nginx to serve static content like images, css and javascript. there we configure error_page 404 /path_to_some_php_script that handle all requests to missing files. error_page directive work like this: when you request some content nginx checks that the requested resource exists. if it doesnt it redirects to the url specified. then you can parse the url and make some conditionals so you can display different type/size of default images.

Comment: Does it work if I have to show different default images based on different scenarios?

Comment: it's all in your hands to write the handler ... generally you might do what you want. just play with the url ....

Answer (score 0):

you can use either JS

```
<img src='earth.jpg' onerror='this.src=/somewhereovertherainbow.jpg' />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove `<img />` tag with jQuery if referenced image does not exist:

```
<img src="image.png" onerror="$(this).remove()" />
```

or:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#img1").error(function () { $(this).remove() });
  });
</script>

<img id="img1" src="image.png" />
```